# How to Run a Specific Service in a Dockerfile with Multiple Services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a flag I can pass into `docker-compose` that can specify a single service within it to run?

For example:

```
version: "2"
services:
  fetcher:
    build:
      context: ./build1/
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://132.216.27.81:23012/
  fetcher2:
    build:
      context: ./build2/
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://132.216.27.81:23012/
    ports:
      - "45760:8121"
```

Is there a way for me to merely specify that I want to `up` only `fetcher2`?

Reason being I have multiple fetcher processes that run upon `docker-compose up` and I would much rather only select to rerun some specific ones that have failed for whatever reason rather than having all of my fetchers re-fetch info that is already stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker-compose up fetcher2